# Does Google API Client use https?

Tags: android, ssl, google-drive-api

In my android App
I am uploading some data from device to Google Drive using GoogleApiClient
(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

I want to know whether this data transfer happen over a SSL connection ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: it's safe to assume that all Google APIs run over https